# Run function on table_1 with every value from table_2 as a parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have 2 following tables:

Table: product_hierarchy

```
SELECT * FROM product_hierarchy;
HEAD: parent_id, child_id
ROW 1: 1000, 1001
ROW 2: 1000, 1002
ROW 3: 1000, 1003
ROW 4: 2000, 2001
ROW 5: 2000, 2002
... etc.
```

Table: attribute_names

```
SELECT * FROM attribute_names;
HEAD: aname
ROW 1: product_name
ROW 2: price
ROW 3: height
ROW 4: width
ROW 5: length
... etc.
```

I need to run a function called

`FUNCTION get_attribute(id NUMBER(10), attribute_name VARCHAR2(256)) RETURNS VARCHAR2`

- on every child_id in table product_hierarchy,
- using every attibute name in table attribute_names

and then combine everything into table product_hierarchy.

The final table should look like this for example:

Table: product_hierarchy

```
SELECT * FROM table_hierarchy;
HEAD: parent_id, child_id, product_name, price, height, width, length
ROW 1: 1000, 1001, box1, 20, 10, 10, 10
ROW 2: 1000, 1002, box2, 15, 9, 9, 9
ROW 3: 1000, 1003, box3, 30, 15, 15, 15
ROW 4: 2000, 2001, panel1, 5, 10, 10, 2
ROW 5: 2000, 2002, panel2, 10, 20, 20, 3
... etc.
```

I can't seem to come up with an appropriate SQL query that does the thing I need. Anyone up to the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all data in a long list is doable:

```
SELECT 
  ph.parent_id, 
  ph.child_id,
  th.aname AS attribute_label,
  get_attribute(child_id, th.aname) AS attribute
FROM 
  product_hierarchy ph
  CROSS JOIN table_hierarchy th
```

To get those attributes as separate columns is a tough job. Even when you use the `pivot` features of Oracle, you cannot do this for a variable/unknown number of values. You have to specify the labels that are made into columns.

So I hope the query above will do.

If not, I think you would have to query all the labels first for table_hierarchy, then, you can build a dynamic SQL statement, based on the labels you found, and translate every one of them into a column. Then, you can return that data from a function. Not a very nice solution, but I think there is no other way if you must return the data in exact that structure.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Could you please show an example of that dynamic SQL statement? I'd like to keep the above mentioned structure.